# ERROR al conectar base de datos mysql a un documento php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Buen día, quien este leyendo esto de antemano le agradezco que se tome el tiempo de analizar mi caso.

Soy un estudiante de ingeniería en sistemas, y en una materia como proyecto se me encargo hacer un servidor web y que cuando entre, este pueda acceder a una base de datos que ya tengo creada.

Logre realizar todo lo que me pidió mi profesor excepto una cosa... conectar la base de datos a mi interfaz de `php`. He buscado por distintos foros, videos, etc. y por mas que sigo los pasos no puedo conectar mi base de datos. Al cargar la pagina donde requiero que se utilice mi base me aparece un anuncio diciendo que la conexión ha fallado

> (Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Fallo temporal en la resolución del nombre in /opt/lampp/htdocs/proyecto/SII.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Fallo temporal en la resolución del nombre in /opt/lampp/htdocs/proyecto/SII.php on line 8)

He intentado con distintas formas de conectarla y no sale, ¿me podrían ayudar?.

Si es así dejaré la conexión de mi base de datos para que la revisen y a su vez la versión de mi `php` para que sea una respuesta mas acertada.

Conexión:

```
<?php
function conectar(){
  $usuario="root";
  $password="mi_contraseña";
  $servidor="127.0.0.1";
  $db ="SII";
  $mysql =new mysqli($usuario,$password,$db);
}
 ?>
```

Archivo donde mando a llamar la conexión:

```
<?php
include ("SII.php");
$con=conectar();
 ?>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Registrarse</title>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css"
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php require "partials/header.php"?>
    <h1>Registrar</h1>
      <span>o <a href="iniciarS.php">iniciar sesion</a></span>
      <form action="registrar.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="numero de control" placeholder="Por favor introduce tu numero de control">
        <input type="text" name="Nombre" placeholder="Por favor introduce tu Nombre">
        <input type="text" name="Apellido paterno" placeholder="Por favor introduce tu apellido paterno">
        <input type="text" name="Apellido materno" placeholder="Por favor introduce tu apellido materno">
        <input type="text" name="Direccion" placeholder="Por favor introduce tu direccion">
        <input type="int number" name="telefonico" placeholder="Por favor introduce tu numero telefonico">
        <input type="date" name="" value="" min="1950-01-01" max="2019-12-31">
        <input type="password" name="NIP" placeholder="Por favor introduce tu NIP">
        <input type="password" name="Confirma tu NIP" placeholder="Confirma tu NIP">
        <input type="submit" value="Registrar">
    </body>
    </html>
```

versiones utilizadas:

- `PHP`:7.2.24
- `Apache` :2.4.38
- `MariaDB`:10.4.8

Answer (score 2):

En tu linea 8 te hace falta colocar el servidor $servidor. De esta manera:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$password,$db);
```